# why doesnt the persian word add behind a number?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

i have a really strange problem in java script.
look at these codes and run the app:

```js
const number = 200000;
const persianMoney = "تومان";

//pay attention to these lines:
console.log("way 1:");
console.log(number + persianMoney);
console.log(persianMoney + number);

console.log("way 2:");
console.log(`${number}${persianMoney}`);
console.log(`${persianMoney}${number}`);

console.log("way 3:");
console.log(String(number) + persianMoney);
console.log(persianMoney + String(number));

console.log("way 4:");
console.log(`${String(number)}${persianMoney}`);
console.log(`${persianMoney}${String(number)}`);

console.log("way 5:");
console.log(String(number + persianMoney));
console.log(String(persianMoney + number));
```

all of the outputs are the same!! all of the outputs are `200000تومان`! but why word `تومان` is not behind `200000` in some outputs? even here, i cant put `تومان` behind `200000`! but why it is like that? i cant understand it. i tested concatenation in 5 ways but none of them were correct! how can i solve this problem? thanks for helping.

Comment: Sice Persian is written right to left, the Unicode bidi algorithm applies. Digits have neutral directionality, so they will match the directionality of surrounding text.

Comment: So there is no solution for this, am i right?

Comment: You haven't yet stated what you want. All you have said so far is that the results are "not correct". The results are correct according to the Unicode bidi algorithm. But maybe you were expecting something different, like maybe `تومان‎200000`? You can insert an explicit left-to-right marker to force the number to render LTR: `console.log(persianMoney + "\u200e" + number)`. I'm guessing. In the future please state the result you expect, rather than just saying "I'm not getting the correct answer." (You keep saying "behind", but it's not clear what you mean by that. The letters do not overlap.)

Comment: But i said my point! I said i cant put تومان behind the number, why it is like that, how can i solve this problem and these sentences mean that i want to put تومان behind the bumber, please give me the solution. But what you said is correct too. I could say what i want more clear. So i'll do this next time. And for your answer. Thank you. It was ok. If you like, post your comment as an answer so i could mark your answer. Thank you again my friend.

Comment: "behind" is confusing because this is a left/right layout issue, not front/back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Raymand Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen). My understanding is that you want to have the currency name تومان after the number 200000. To keep the Arabic/Persian word in the same direction as the Latin word i.e. in a Left-To-Right LTR direction.

One possible way to do that is to add the LTR code `\u200E`

```js
const number = 200000;
const persianMoney = "تومان";
const ltr = "\u200E";
console.log(persianMoney + ltr + " " + number);
```